# What exactly is a cofactor and how is the sign chart derived?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Given

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & \dots & a_{1j} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{i1} & \dots & a_{ij}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I know the cofactor is $A_{ij}=M_{ij}(-1)^{i+j}$ where $M_{ij}$ is the minor of an element. But what does that even mean? What does it mean to take the cofactor of a matrix, is there a geometric visualization of this or anything?

Second, where does the sign chart below come from, and why do I have to use it to take the row cofactor sum to find the determinant of the matrix?
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
+ & - & + \\
- & + & - \\
+ & - & +
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I have a decent understanding of why $\Delta x=\Delta_1$, but it's cofactor expansions and the sign chart that I don't understand (but can do/use).

Comment: Think of the cofactor of an entry as the derivative of the determinant with respect to that entry; it tells you (up to sign) how fast the determinant changes when you changes that entry.

Comment: If you really want to know: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#Proof

Comment: I think of the sign chart as related to the property of determinants that switching adjacent rows (or columns) in a matrix switches the sign of the determinant